# OpenACC compiler: How to download and use CAPS compiler

Tags: openacc

I want to write OpenACC programs, but I can not find a compiler to write this kind of program.
The PGI compiler is not free for some countries like Iran.
I want to ask how to download CAPS compiler, I can not find any link
In one post linked to [this page](http://www.caps-entreprise.com/products/caps-compilers/) But this page is not valid.

Comment: University of Houston has an [open source OpenACC compiler](https://github.com/uhhpctools/openuh-openacc).

Comment: GCC 5 comes with a somewhat incomplete implementation: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/OpenACC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, CAPS went out of business, so that compiler is no longer available. The OpenUH research compiler is one option, or the PGI free trial, which you've already said is not available for you. The Cray compiler would only be available if you have access to a Cray system. As someone already said, GCC5 has some support for OpenACC, but it's far from complete, so it probably won't meet your needs just yet. If you're not able to use the PGI compiler trial, then OpenUH is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I  use Pgi compiler. In this link you can download it (first need to register on site and then give 30days free trial )
[Download PGI compiler & tools](http://www.pgroup.com/support/download_pgi2016.php?view=current)

Answer (score 0):

GNU is a good case. I use OPENACC with gnu for FORTRAN programming.